# Show how the Diophantine sets are closed under concatenation.

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, computability

It follows easily from [Matiyasevich's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich.27s_theorem) that the Diophantine sets are closed under concatenation.  I am trying to figure out the *mechanism* by which they are closed under concatenation.  In other words...

> Given Diophantine polynomials $p(x \, | \, a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and $q(x \, | \, b_1, \dots, b_m)$, find a Diophantine polynomial $r(x \, | \, c_1, \dots, c_k)$ (described in terms of $p$ and $q$) such that if:
>
> 1. There exist $a_1, \dots, a_n$ such that $p(x_1 \, | \, a_1, \dots, a_n) = 0$, and
> 2. There exist $b_1, \dots, b_m$ such that $q(x_2 \, | \, b_1, \dots, b_m) = 0$, then
> 3. There exist $c_1, \dots, c_k$ such that $r(2^{\lfloor\log x_2\rfloor} \cdot x_1 + x_2 \, | \, c_1, \dots, c_k) = 0$

Any advice?

Comment: I think you need $\lceil \log x_2 \rceil$ to properly concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matiyasevich gives a polynomial for exponentiation, call it
$$
e(x,y,z) = 0 \iff x=y^z
$$
then to concatenate $x_1$ and $x_2$ we need a polynomial combining
$$
e(\beta,2,\alpha) = 0 \\
x_2<\beta<2 x_2 \\
x=\beta x_1+x_2
$$
call this $S(x,x_1,x_2)=0 \iff x=2^{\lceil \log_2 x_2 \rceil}x_1+x_2$.

Identify the variables
$$
(c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots,c_k) = (x_1,x_2,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m)
$$
then
$$
r(x|c_1,\ldots,c_k) = S(x,c_1,c_2)^2+p(c_1|c_3,\ldots,c_{n+2})^2+
q(c_2|c_{n+3},\ldots,c_k)^2
$$
satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thank you.